# jquery load() function only loading some of my items some of the time

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I make multiple load calls to display graphs saved as html. The issue I am having is I can't consistently get all items to load. Sometime they all work sometimes not. I am currently developing and running the site locally.

Script call in my header

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/about/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`

One of the pages I am having trouble with

```
{% extends "about/DataProject.html" %}
{% block Dashboard %}
<div class="col-md-16">
<h5>Stock Price</h5>
<article class="content-nohover" id="stock_aapl"></article>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h5>Recent Twitter Sentiment</h5>
    <article class="content-nohover"  >
        <div id="sent_aapl"></div>
    </article>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h5>Recent Tweets About ${{title}} </h5>
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <div class="parent">
            <a class="block" href="{{ tweet.link }}" target="_blank">
                <article class="media content-section">
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="article-metadata">

                        <h6 align="left" style="display: inline;text- align:left">@{{ tweet.author }}</h6>
                        <h6 align="right" style="display: inline;text-align:right;   float:right">Date:{{ tweet.date }} | Sentiment: {{ tweet.score }}</h6>
                    </div>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ tweet.tweet }}</p>
                  </div>
                </article>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <h1>{{ test1 }}</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Functions

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
        // Disable caching of AJAX responses
            cache: false
        });
      $('#stock_aapl').load('{% url 'about-aapl-stock' %}');
      $('#sent_aapl').load('{% url 'about-aapl-sent' %}');
    });
</script>

{% endblock Dashboard %}
```

Comment: set a callback success function for load methods so you can trace the code and see if about-aapl-stock/about-aapl-sent scripts execute successfully even when the page loads broken?

Comment: Something like this?       $('#sent_aapl').load('{% url 'about-aapl-sent' %}', function(data));  I am new to Jquery so help is very appreciated!